# Http Posting using curl library

Tags: curl

I have a written a code for Http posting using curl library.
My Problem is I am not able to send the data to the exact page.
I doubt whether am I able to connect to the specific URL defined.

Code Snippet:

```
include <curl/curl.h>

main()
{
  CURL *curl;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,     
  "http://www.example.com/web5/web/Default.aspx");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=Hello World");
  curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

When I check it from the Browser in this ways:
http://www.example.com/web5/web/Default.aspx?data=Hello World
It works fine.

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.